# pages and header are not displayed in the app.js

Tags: reactjs

I can't see my Pages or Header in Localhost:3000

Here you can see the App.ja

```
import React from "react";
import { signInWithGoogle } from "./services/fireBase";
import Header from "./pages/layout/Header";
import Message from "./pages/Message
const App = () => {

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <h1>LernApp</h1>
    <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign In with Google</button>
    <h1>{localStorage.getItem("name")}</h1>  
    <Header />
    <Message />
    </div>  
  );

};
export default App;
```

it is a empty page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4szu.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this. This is called React Fragments to wrap multiple HTML elements.

```
return (
<> 
<div className="App">
<h1>LernApp</h1>
<button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign In with Google</button>
<h1>{localStorage.getItem("name")}</h1>  
<Header />
<Message />
</div>  
</>
  );
```

Comment: Do you have any desk etc so I can check deeply?

Comment: I think the problem are the MUI Material. Install is not correct: (base) 
frontend % npm install @material-ui/
core

up to date, audited 851 packages in 1s

107 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

1 high severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: try to uninstall the mui materials and regain install the package. maybe works,

Comment: I did it, but the page is write again

Comment: can you explain deeply your code on https://codesandbox.io/?

Answer (score 0):

check 1: While Importing Pages or Header check proper folder Structure .
check 2: try using fragmentation for multiple renders.
let us know it is help full or not.

```
  return (
<> 
<div className="App">
<h1>LernApp</h1>
<button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign In with Google</button>
<h1>{localStorage.getItem("name")}</h1>  
<Header />
<Message />
</div>  
</>
  );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).